# Build fails appcenter bot test

Tags: applications, appcenter, development

I recently switched over to elementary os and a friend told me about how easy it is to develop apps for the os. I switch over and the first thing i instantly miss is whatsapp. I use it daily for work and for home so i decided i should write my own app.

I went through your guys documentation, build process. Made the app and installed it on my system. I decided id release it onto the app center for other users and stuff. So i go through the documentation for doing that, link my github. Let the bot go through the build process. And immediately end up with a failing build for something two lines different from the hello world program.

https://github.com/winters-brown/whatsapp-web/issues/3

So i thought it was a fluke, realized im talking to a bot, closed the application and then tried to run the build process again. Only to get smacked in the face with the same issue again.

https://github.com/winters-brown/whatsapp-web/issues/4

I have two problems. It says that it does not have the correct dependency's even though their listed in the meson.build file. my other issue is why is it installing a icon pack over installing those dependencies. How do i fix this so i can release it on the app center. Am i missing something or just suck at developing?